# Jenkins Build Stability/Statisitics Report plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins instance running around 200 jobs. What I need is a plugin to show the build statistics for all the jobs.

1. Total Builds for each project
2. Failures
3. Success
4. Average time per build.

Searched a lot, but couldn't find a proper report plugin. Please help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These are few which you can look depending on how much customization/features you want to do/display:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Build+Stats+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/build-metrics-plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Project+Statistics+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/eXtreme+Feedback+Panel+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/InfluxDB+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CouchDB+Statistics+Plugin

And there is [Dashboard-View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View) too.

Comment: None of these plugins provide a holistic view of the Jobs. I am looking for something like a bar chart. Also the dashboard view plugin, does not pick up the correct number of builds. Is it only pulling 2 weeks data?

Comment: I see that _Global Build Plugin_ does provide graphs. It also has `Statuses filtering` for helping you customize report using filters such as Success/Failures/Unstable/Aborted/... and there is _Average build time_ that can be set under section `Elements displayed on chart`. Did you check those settings?

Comment: Charts provided are not very intuitive I feel. Any other option?

Comment: These are the only ones that i'm aware of.

Comment: These reports are not showing jobs that are created as pipeline type

Comment: How can we create a similar report for pipeline type project @vinay

Comment: @TanviGarg Did you have any luck looking for a plugin that would support pipeline jobs as well?

Comment: @s_neenu I could not find any plugin that supports pipeline type project as of now.

Answer (score 1):

For collecting nodes machine metrics (CPU Time/ Used Memory / Build Time per node etc.), I found the monitoring plugin to be the best.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Monitoring

When it comes to aggregates build times group by job, I couldn't find anything good within Jenkins UI, but if you have a datadog license, you can just enable the datadog Jenkins plugin, configure the datadog api key and hostname in Jenkins Config, and you are good to go.

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-jenkins-datadog/