# How to calculate Jenkins pass and fail percentage of build's?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

How to calculate Jenkins pass and fail percentage of build's?

I have one Jenkins job and it ran 100 times in one week.

I want to calculate automatically number of percentage the times it pass and it fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this answer:

[Jenkins Build Stability/Statisitics Report plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331676/jenkins-build-stability-statisitics-report-plugin)

In case you don't want to use a plugin you can always get the interested stat just greping the job xml files in the file system.

You got all the builds of a particular job under:

```
JENKINS_HOME/JOB_NAME/builds
```

Once there you will have a list of builds (depending by your retention):

```
39
40
41
```

Inside everyone of them you can find the build.xml with the information about the build, this approach can be useful if you need to elaborate in a custom way the dates, in fact you can put them into a DB or plan file and analyse them or produce all the stats you want

Comment: Better to use Audit to DB plugin for DB logging or having some sql executor at the end of job.